# Multicolumn autosearch user control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, user-controls, wpf-controls

I need to create an Auto search control which will show the results as rows as this one http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Editors/lookup-editor.xml. However, I dont need the graphics and checkboxes here. A simple listview like appearance will work.

Please suggest how to create the user control using WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an MVVM approach you could do the following:

- Bind your search Textbox Text member, ListView's ItemsSource and SelectedItem to the ViewModel
- Set 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged' on the TextBox's binding
- In the setter of the property that the TextBox is bound to add logic that searches the ItemsSource collection and sets the SelectedItem bound property.

Something like this:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SearchTerm, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSearchItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Code:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public string SearchTerm 
     {
          get { return searchTerm; }
          set {
                searchTerm = value;
                SelectedSearchItem = SourceCollection.FirstOrDefault(foo => foo.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
          }
     }

     public Foo SelectedSearchItem 
     { 
           get { return selecedSearchItem; } 
           set {
                 selectedSearchItem = value;
                 // Raise PropertyChanged 
           }
     }


     public ObservableCollection<Foo> SourceCollection { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/08/31/wpf-listcollectionview-for-sorting-filtering-and-grouping.aspx) has a nice article on Sorting, Filtering and Grouping ListView.

Basically you set [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) to ListCollectionView.  You can then use the [Filter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc452341.aspx) to filter the ListView.